# Javascript Image animation flashing image bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some javascript for animating a weather radar, but the images flash on each interval. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here's the code I have so far.an.. http://jsfiddle.net/5a2BZ/46/

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2rc1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="slider">
    <div id="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#bar').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
});

var animate = null;
var even = true;

animate = setInterval(function () {

    if (even) {
        $("#bar").css("background-image", "url('http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342653720.jpg')");
        even = false;
    } else { 
        $("#bar").css("background-image", "url('http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342654440.jpg')");
        even = true;
    }

}, 500);



var el = document.getElementById('bar'); 
el.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
el.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
el.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
el.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);

function touchHandler(event){
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

    switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }
    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                              first.screenX, first.screenY,
                              first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                              false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**CSS**

```
#slider {
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 500px;
}

#bar {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    left:30px;
    top:30px;
    height: 355px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 666px;
}
```

Comment: On my phone it ran quite smoothly after i changed the interval to setTimeout and set the timeout to 1000/60

Comment: rather use jquery to show and hide divs, or images, than loading a background image all the time. Loading times causes flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex and Shaun are both correct.

Here is a version that will allow this to work with any number of images (within reason).

http://jsfiddle.net/5a2BZ/66/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2rc1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.j></script>

<style>
.slider {
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 500px;
}

.bar {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    left:30px;
    top:30px;
    height: 355px;
    cursor: pointer;
        width: 666px;
    }

    .bar img {
        display: none;   
    }
</style>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="bar">
        <img src="http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342653720.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342654440.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>​


<script>
$('.bar').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
});

var animate = null,
    i = 0;

animate = setInterval(function () {
    var imgs = $('.bar').children('img'),
        currentImg = imgs.eq(i-1),
        nextImg = imgs.eq(i);

    if (i === 0) {
        currentImg = imgs.eq(imgs.length - 1);
    }            

    currentImg.hide();
    nextImg.show();

    if (i >= imgs.length - 1) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {
        i += 1;
    }

}, 500);



var el = document.getElementById('bar'); 
el.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
el.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
el.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
el.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);

function touchHandler(event){
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

    switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }
    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                              first.screenX, first.screenY,
                              first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                              false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>

​
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for thinking ahead and coding for multiple images. My demo was only for 2, but I needed 10. I had to restructure it a bit since its for a mobile device, and my phone wont keep animating using images if I move it. CSS backgrounds are alright though. Not sure why, but I modded your version to create what I will ultimately use. Thanks again! Here's my final version... http://jsfiddle.net/5a2BZ/77/

Answer (score 2):

Use a static image that matches your radar image as the background. It's not the best solution, but seems to work for me. Here is the CSS and HTML. I didn't change the javascript.

```
#slider {
width: 700px;
border: 1px solid #000;
height: 500px;
}

#bar {
border: 1px solid #000;
left:30px;
top:30px;
height: 355px;
cursor: pointer;
width: 666px;
}
#well{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index:-1;
position:relative;
background-image: url('http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342653720.jpg');
}
```

And wrap your bar around a well like:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="well">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

​
Here is the solution in full: http://jsfiddle.net/5a2BZ/70/

Comment: Thank you, you were a lot of help!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would rather have a couple of DIV's with the correct images, and show and hide those divs when needed, this way you will not have any flickering at all.

Some simple code like this:

```
    <div id="slider" class="Normal" style="position: relative; ">

<img alt="" src="http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342653720.jpg" style="" class="bar img1">
<img alt="" src="http://static.baynews9.com/images/wx/bn9/radar/7_county/1342654440.jpg" style="display:none;" class="bar img2">

    </div>
```

Then you can have something like this in you JavaScript:

```
if (even) {
        $(".bar").hide();
        $(".img1").show();
        even = false;
    } else { 
        $(".bar").hide();
        $(".img2").show();
        even = true;}
```

here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/xnePc/4/

This will first hide all images with a class of banner, then show a specific image of class "img1" / "img2". The img1 and img2 could be id's as well.

have a look at this library too, for more ideas:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, you were a lot of help!

Answer (score 0):

The flashing occurs because the image is changing (and loading again) in every refresh. The old background is cleared before the new one ends downloading from its source. If you really want no flashing to occur you should use two divs, positioned one on the top of the other, and alternate orders on each iteration.